# RAILS: Prevent creating a record twice if two requests are sent at the exact same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using an external API which for whatever reason posts every request twice at the exact same time. This is out of my control.

This causes records to be created twice in my mysql database.

I do have a validation in my model that checks if a record exists. This works fine if the two requests are sent after each other, but doesn't work if the two requests are sent at the same time.

The only thing I can think of is creating a job for each request that is executed at some random amount of time from now and validating the uniqueness in my model. But I wonder if there is a better way of dealing with this?

So how do I deal with this issue?

Comment: Add some uniqueness constraints either in db or in model?

Comment: You could use the [Rack::Throttle gem](https://github.com/dryruby/rack-throttle/blob/master/README.md) that lets you limit requests from the same client on the middleware layer (before the request reaches rails).

Comment: You should also have a unique index in your database to avoid race conditions which can occur in situations like this if you only have a application level validation. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Answer (score 0):

What may help you is adding a unique validation to your model and uniqueness constraint to the DB itself. The reason is that the model validation won't be enough, it will be needed just to make your application "aware" of that restriction. What will actually prevent you from saving two duplicate records is the DB constraint.

So when two duplicating requests will successfully pass your validation, the first of them will create a record and the second will try to do so, too, but MySQL adapter will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` which you'll be able to handle.

That's actually nothing more than a common way to handle race conditions. So basically add unique index to the corresponding table and it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Active Record uniqueness validation does not guarantee uniqueness at
>   the database level

The solution is straightforward to implement, you just need to enforce
uniqueness at the database level as well as at the model level.
You can create a database index and then require that the index to be unique

The [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) actually suggests the same

> uniqueness helper validates that the attribute's value is unique right
>   before the object gets saved. It does not create a uniqueness
>   constraint in the database, so it may happen that two different
>   database connections create two records with the same value for a
>   column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must create a
>   unique index on that column in your database.